# How to change tablespace for a partition in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

How to change the tablespace for an existing partition in PostgreSQL 12?

The "Oracle" way of doing it `ALTER TABLE x MOVE PARTITION y TABLESPACE z` is not supported.

If I use `ALTER TABLE x SET TABLESPACE z`, it doesn't affect its partitions.

What other options do I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PostgreSQL, partitions are tables in their own right. So all you have to do is to move the partition itself:

```
ALTER TABLE y SET TABLESPACE z;
```

Comment: Doh... So simple....Thanks!